# How to obtain file permission using roottools

Tags: android, file, permissions, root, roottools

I want to obtain linux file permissions without parsing ls -l.
Since I will be using RootTools, I see it has a [Permissions](http://roottools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Developmental/doc/index.html) class, but how should I obtain permission data of a File into that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RootToolsInternalMethods have getPermissions(String) method, but they can only be accessed in RootTools class

From RootTools source

```
private static final RootToolsInternalMethods getInternals() {
    if (rim == null) {
        RootToolsInternalMethods.getInstance();
        return rim;
    } else {
        return rim;
    }
}
```

Seems like I have to modify RootTools source and get the permissions from ls -l output

```
getInternals().getPermissions("ls -l output line");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify source use reflection:

```
private Permissions RootToolsInternalMethods_getPermissions(String line)
{
    try
    {
        RootTools rootTools = new RootTools();
        Method method = rootTools.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getInternals");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        RootToolsInternalMethods rootToolsInternalMethods = (RootToolsInternalMethods)method.invoke(rootTools);
        return rootToolsInternalMethods.getPermissions(line);
    }
    catch (Exception ignore) {}

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is also a good idea, but you need to be careful not to forget this when updating RootTools, if it changes.